# How to merge vectors of different length in an alternating manner

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to do the following in matlab. The numbers given are just an example. I am working with very large datasets, so an elegant solution is preferable.

I have two vectors where one is a single digit larger than the other:

```
a = [3  6 8 2 4 86 64 3]' %// 8 digits

b = [23 5 7 2 8 4  5]' %// 7 digits
```

I would like to combine them in an alternating fashion so they become:

```
c = [3 23 6 5 8 7 2 2 4 8 86 4 64 5 3] %// 15 digits
```

can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c(1:2:2*numel(a)-1) = a;
c(2:2:end-1) = b;
```

An alternative (I doubt it would be more efficient but you can test it out on your real data)

```
c = [a'; [b', NaN]];
c(:);
c(end) = [];
```

Comment: Just to note, neither method works if `a` is longer than `b`.

Comment: @IKavanagh not sure what you mean, both methods assume `a` is one element longer than `b` as specified in the question...?

Comment: Ooops, my mistake. I meant to say neither method works if `b` is longer than `a`. Its only a caveat on the off chance the OP can't guarantee `a` will always be longer.

Comment: @IKavanagh It's trivial to account for that though should the OP require it. As it stands, I feel this answer fully answers the question asked.